# How to intersect two files in Python using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

I have two dataframes, A and B, that have some common column names. Like that:

```
A                            B
Date Birth             Date Place City
156    0               642    M     K
521    1               765    O     L
765    1               111    S     K
832    0               521    M     S
```

I need to get a new dataframe which will consist of the intersection of A and B basd on their common column + data from 2nd dataframe:

```
Date  Place  City
765    O      L
521    M      S
```

Is there any faster way than iterate through the items, as i'm trying to do?'

```
f=''
for i in A['Date'].iteritems():
    for j in B['Date'].iteritems():
        if i==j:
           f.to_csv([j]+B['Place']+['City'])
```

Comment: You'll most likely use the `DataFrame.merge` functionality. Check the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
print pd.merge(A,B, on=['Date']).drop('Birth', axis=1)
   Date Place City
0   521     M    S
1   765     O    L
```

Next solution create subset with column `Date` and then [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) it with `DataFrame` `B`:

```
print pd.merge(A[['Date']],B, on=['Date'])
   Date Place City
0   521     M    S
1   765     O    L
```